# Class is not defined despite being imported

Tags: python, class, module

I seem to have run into a really confusing error. Despite importing the .py file containing my class, Python is insistent that the class doesn't actually exist.

Class definition in testmodule.py:

```
class Greeter:
    def __init__(self, arg1=None):
        self.text = arg1

    def say_hi(self):
        return self.text
```

main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import testmodule

sayinghi = Greeter("hello world!")
print(sayinghi.say_hi())
```

I have a theory that the import is not working as it should. How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 41):

Use the fully-qualified name:

```
sayinghi = testmodule.Greeter("hello world!")
```

There is an alternative form of `import` that would bring `Greeter` into your namespace:

```
from testmodule import Greeter
```

Answer (score 25):

```
import testmodule
# change to
from testmodule import Greeter
```

or

```
import testmodule
sayinghi = Greeter("hello world!")
# change to
import testmodule
sayinghi = testmodule.Greeter("hello world!")
```

You imported the module/package, but you need to reference the class inside it.

You could also do this instead

```
from testmodule import *
```

but then beware of [namespace pollution](http://bytebaker.com/2008/07/30/python-namespaces/)