# Make modules available globally

Tags: python, module, global-variables, global

I'm trying to make my modules available globally

**Filesystem structure**

```
main.py
module_static.py
folder/module_dynamic.py # this is example, but imagine 100s of modules
```

**main.py**

```
print('Loading module_static')
import module_static
module_static.test()

# Trying to make module_static available globally
globals()['module_static'] = module_static
__all__ = ['module_static']

print('Loading module_dynamic')
import sys
sys.path.append('./folder/')
import module_dynamic
module_dynamic.test()
```

**module_static.py**

```
def test():
    print('  -> This is module_static')
```

**module_dynamic.py**

```
def test():
    print('  -> This is module_dynamic')
    module_static.test()
```

Running **main.py** creates the following execution flow **main.py -> module_dynamic.py -> module_static.py**

[image]

So as you can see:

- Loading of modules is working properly
- However, despite trying to make `module_static` available globally, it isn't working a **module_dynamic.py** throws an error saying `module_static` doesn't exist

**How can I make `module_static.py` available in `module_dynamic.py` (ideally without having to write any additional code in `module_dynamic.py`)?**

Comment: please add the entire code of `module_dynamic.py`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722415/class-is-not-defined-despite-being-imported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not saying it's good practice, but you can do

**main.py**

```
import builtins
import module_static
builtins.module_static = module_static
```

This should allow you to use `module_static` from anywhere.

More info on `builtins`: [How to make a cross-module variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142545/how-to-make-a-cross-module-variable#answer-142566)

Answer (score 2):

It can't work the way you expect. globals() return a dict of globals variables in your script. Maybe this may help you to understand

[image]

You can take a look at this course for better understanding

https://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php

Anyway, **you will have to import the module to use it**.

If it's just a local tool for your personnal use, you could  move it to the folder
`{Python_installation_folder}/Lib`.

Then, in any script, you will be able to do

```
import module_static
```

and use your module.

If you want to share your module with other people, publish (upload) it on PyPi. You could follow the tutorial bellow
https://anweshadas.in/how-to-upload-a-package-in-pypi-using-twine/

Comment: Why can't I use `globals()` to make the module available globally? What I would like to do is control all my modules from `main.py` and not have to worry about module loading from the dynamic modules (I have 100s of them)

Comment: it doesn't works this way. globals() return a dict of all variables global to your script (at the opposite of local variables which are defined in functions / methods, and doesn't exists in your script's root). See the edited answer